# Delphi (FMX): DCPCrypt2 in Windows produces different result in Android/IOS

Tags: php, delphi, encryption, openssl, rawbytestring

I am trying to write a function that returns the same result in Delphi (RAD Studio 10.2) as the following piece of code in PHP:

```
<?php
  $method = 'AES-256-CTR';
  $data = 'Hello, world!';
  $key = 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuini';
  $vector = 'bf49ea9d61104d8c'; 
  $crypt = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, 0, $vector);
  echo $crypt;
?>
```

I have come up with this function in Pascal (using the DCPcrypt v2.1 library written by David Barton):

```
procedure TMainForm.Encrypt1ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
  Key, Vector: RawByteString;
  Data, Crypt: RawByteString;
begin
  Data := 'Hello, world!';                    
  SetLength(Crypt, Length(Data));
  Key := 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuini';  
  Vector := 'bf49ea9d61104d8c';               
  Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
  try
    Cipher.Init(Key[1], 256, @Vector[1]);
    Cipher.EncryptCTR(Data[1], Crypt[1], Length(Data));
  finally
    Cipher.Free;
  end;
  EncryptEdit.Text := DCPBase64.Base64EncodeStr(Crypt);
end;
```

And indeed this works (in Windows). Both PHP and Pascal return: `pEP16OOxov9QDfraIg==`

However, if I compile the same code for Android and run it on my tablet, I get a very different result. Why is that?

I did read the documentation about converting code for fmx, specifically the stuff that deals with string handling, but I still don't understand why. Even if RawByteString would be 0-based instead of 1-based, I still get a difference (tried with [0] instead of [1]). A RawByteString does not have a codepage attached, right? So the problem can't be caused by some string conversion (I think). So what is going on here?

Comment: Pick a text encoding and be explicit about it

Comment: 1. Did you try to use pointer(Key) pointer(Data) instead of Key[1], Data[1] ? 2. Also check the content of Crypt - problem may be about base64 conversion.

Answer (score 3):

After working on this for 3 days, I finally got it working. The key was to completely eliminate the use of strings and only use the TBytes based routines in DCPCrypt.
The code below is a test program for testing all the different chaining modes that DCPCrypt supports. I also added a function that implements the four padding modes I found here (for use with CBC and ECB):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)
as well as zero padding and random padding.
I chose not to use DCPCrypt's own Base64 functions, because they turned out not to be compatible with FMX. Instead I use their counterparts from the System.NetEncoding unit.
Please, I consider myself to be just an average programmer, so I expect the true Delphi wizzards among you to find lots to criticize. But that's ok. I will adapt the code if good feedback is given. 
As it is now, the code works and produces results that are compatible with PHP's openssl functions (tested with CTR mode). I only post this here in the hopes that it might be useful to someone looking for the same solution I was.

```
    unit MainUnit;

    interface

    uses
      System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.NetEncoding,
      FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts,
      FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Edit, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
      DCPcrypt2, DCPsha256, DCPblockciphers, DCPrijndael;

    type
      TChainingMode = (cmCBC, cmCFB8bit, cmCFBblock, cmOFB, cmCTR, cmECB);
      TPaddingMode = (pmZeroPadding, pmANSIX923, pmISO10126, pmISO7816, pmPKCS7, pmRandomPadding);

    type
      TMainForm = class(TForm)
        ScrollBox: TScrollBox;
        KeySizeLabel: TLabel;
        ChainingLabel: TLabel;
        EncodingLabel: TLabel;
        PaddingLabel: TLabel;
        KeyLabel: TLabel;
        InitVectorLabel: TLabel;
        DataLabel: TLabel;
        DecryptedLabel: TLabel;
        CipherLabel: TLabel;
        EncryptedLabel: TLabel;
        rbRijndael: TRadioButton;
        rb128bit: TRadioButton;
        rb256bit: TRadioButton;
        rbANSI: TRadioButton;
        rbUTF8: TRadioButton;
        rbUnicode: TRadioButton;
        rbCBC: TRadioButton;
        rbOFB: TRadioButton;
        rbCTR: TRadioButton;
        rbECB: TRadioButton;
        rbCFB8bit: TRadioButton;
        rbCFBblock: TRadioButton;
        rbZeroPadding: TRadioButton;
        rbANSIX923: TRadioButton;
        rbISO10126: TRadioButton;
        rbISO7816: TRadioButton;
        rbPKCS7: TRadioButton;
        rbRandomPadding: TRadioButton;
        KeyEdit: TEdit;
        InitVectorEdit: TEdit;
        DataMemo: TMemo;
        EncryptedMemo: TMemo;
        DecryptedMemo: TMemo;
        EncryptButton: TButton;
        DecryptButton: TButton;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure EncryptButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure DecryptButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
      public
        procedure GetOptions(var Key: TBytes; var KeySize: integer; var InitVector: TBytes;
                  var Encoding: TEncoding; var ChainingMode: TChainingMode; var PaddingMode: TPaddingMode);
      end;

    var
      MainForm: TMainForm;

    implementation

    {$R *.fmx}
    {$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}

    function BytesToHex(B: TBytes): string;
    var
      I: integer;
    begin
      Result := '';
      for I := Low(B) to High(B) do Result := Result + IntToHex(B[I]) + ' ';
    end;

    procedure BytePadding(var Data: TBytes; BlockSize: integer; PaddingMode: TPaddingMode);
    // Supports: ANSI X.923, ISO 10126, ISO 7816, PKCS7, zero padding and random padding
    var
      I, DataBlocks, DataLength, PaddingStart, PaddingCount: integer;
    begin
      BlockSize := BlockSize div 8; // convert bits to bytes
      // Zero and Random padding do not use end-markers, so if Length(Data) is a multiple of BlockSize, no padding is needed
      if PaddingMode in [pmZeroPadding, pmRandomPadding] then
        if Length(Data) mod BlockSize = 0 then Exit;
      DataBlocks := (Length(Data) div BlockSize) + 1;
      DataLength := DataBlocks * BlockSize;
      PaddingCount := DataLength - Length(Data);
      // ANSIX923, ISO10126 and PKCS7 store the padding length in a 1 byte end-marker, so any padding length > $FF is not supported
      if PaddingMode in [pmANSIX923, pmISO10126, pmPKCS7] then
        if PaddingCount > $FF then Exit;
      PaddingStart := Length(Data);
      SetLength(Data, DataLength);
      case PaddingMode of
        pmZeroPadding, pmANSIX923, pmISO7816: // fill with $00 bytes
          FillChar(Data[PaddingStart], PaddingCount, 0);
        pmPKCS7: // fill with PaddingCount bytes
          FillChar(Data[PaddingStart], PaddingCount, PaddingCount);
        pmRandomPadding, pmISO10126: // fill with random bytes
          for I := PaddingStart to DataLength-1 do Data[I] := Random($FF);
      end;
      case PaddingMode of
        pmANSIX923, pmISO10126:
          Data[DataLength-1] := PaddingCount; // set end-marker with number of bytes added
        pmISO7816:
          Data[PaddingStart] := $80; // set fixed end-markder $80
      end;
    end;

    procedure EncryptAES(const Data: TBytes; var Crypt: TBytes; const Key: TBytes; KeySize: integer;
        const InitVector: TBytes; ChainingMode: TChainingMode; PaddingMode: TPaddingMode); overload;
    var
      Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
    begin
      Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
      try
        Cipher.Init(Key[0], KeySize, @InitVector[0]);
        // Copy Data => Crypt
        Crypt := Copy(Data, 0, Length(Data));
        // Padd Crypt to required length (for Block based algorithms)
        if ChainingMode in [cmCBC, cmECB] then
          BytePadding(Crypt, Cipher.BlockSize, PaddingMode);
        // Encrypt Crypt using the algorithm specified in ChainingMode
        case ChainingMode of
          cmCBC: Cipher.EncryptCBC(Crypt[0], Crypt[0], Length(Crypt));
          cmCFB8bit: Cipher.EncryptCFB8bit(Crypt[0], Crypt[0], Length(Crypt));
          cmCFBblock: Cipher.EncryptCFBblock(Crypt[0], Crypt[0], Length(Crypt));
          cmOFB: Cipher.EncryptOFB(Crypt[0], Crypt[0], Length(Crypt));
          cmCTR: Cipher.EncryptCTR(Crypt[0], Crypt[0], Length(Crypt));
          cmECB: Cipher.EncryptECB(Crypt[0], Crypt[0]);
        end;

      finally
        Cipher.Free;
      end;
    end;

    procedure DecryptAES(const Crypt: TBytes; var Data: TBytes; const Key: TBytes; KeySize: integer;
        const InitVector: TBytes; ChainingMode: TChainingMode; PaddingMode: TPaddingMode); overload;
    var
      Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
      I: integer;
    begin
      Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
      try
        Cipher.Init(Key[0], KeySize, @InitVector[0]);
        // Copy Crypt => Data
        Data := Copy(Crypt, 0, Length(Crypt));
        // Decrypt Data using the algorithm specified in ChainingMode
        case ChainingMode of
          cmCBC: Cipher.DecryptCBC(Data[0], Data[0], Length(Data));
          cmCFB8bit: Cipher.DecryptCFB8bit(Data[0], Data[0], Length(Data));
          cmCFBblock: Cipher.DecryptCFBblock(Data[0], Data[0], Length(Data));
          cmOFB: Cipher.DecryptOFB(Data[0], Data[0], Length(Data));
          cmCTR: Cipher.DecryptCTR(Data[0], Data[0], Length(Data));
          cmECB: Cipher.DecryptECB(Data[0], Data[0]);
        end;
        // Correct the length of Data, based on the used PaddingMode (only for Block based algorithms)
        if ChainingMode in [cmCBC, cmECB] then
          case PaddingMode of
            pmANSIX923, pmISO10126, pmPKCS7: // these modes store the original Padding count in the last byte
              SetLength(Data, Length(Data) - Data[Length(Data)-1]);
            pmISO7816: // this mode uses a fixed end-marker. Find it and correct length accordingly.
              for I := Length(Data)-1 downto 0 do
                if Data[I] = $80 then
                begin
                  SetLength(Data, I);
                  Break;
                end;
          end;

      finally
        Cipher.Free;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      EncryptedMemo.Lines.Clear;
      DecryptedMemo.Lines.Clear;
    end;

    procedure TMainForm.GetOptions(var Key: TBytes; var KeySize: integer; var InitVector: TBytes;
              var Encoding: TEncoding; var ChainingMode: TChainingMode; var PaddingMode: TPaddingMode);
    begin
      KeySize := 256;
      Encoding := TEncoding.ANSI;
      ChainingMode := cmCBC;
      PaddingMode := pmPKCS7;

      if rb128bit.IsChecked then KeySize := 128;
      if rb256bit.IsChecked then KeySize := 256;

      if rbCBC.IsChecked then ChainingMode := cmCBC;
      if rbCFB8bit.IsChecked then ChainingMode := cmCFB8bit;
      if rbCFBblock.IsChecked then ChainingMode := cmCFBblock;
      if rbOFB.IsChecked then ChainingMode := cmOFB;
      if rbCTR.IsChecked then ChainingMode := cmCTR;
      if rbECB.IsChecked then ChainingMode := cmECB;

      if rbZeroPadding.IsChecked then PaddingMode := pmZeroPadding;
      if rbANSIX923.IsChecked then PaddingMode := pmANSIX923;
      if rbISO10126.IsChecked then PaddingMode := pmISO10126;
      if rbISO7816.IsChecked then PaddingMode := pmISO7816;
      if rbPKCS7.IsChecked then PaddingMode := pmPKCS7;
      if rbRandomPadding.IsChecked then PaddingMode := pmRandomPadding;

      if rbANSI.IsChecked then Encoding := TEncoding.ANSI;
      if rbUTF8.IsChecked then Encoding := TEncoding.UTF8;
      if rbUnicode.IsChecked then Encoding := TEncoding.Unicode;

      Key := Encoding.GetBytes(KeyEdit.Text);
      InitVector := Encoding.GetBytes(InitVectorEdit.Text);
    end;

    procedure TMainForm.EncryptButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Keysize: integer;
      Encoding: TEncoding;
      ChainingMode: TChainingMode;
      PaddingMode: TPaddingMode;
      Key, InitVector, Data, Crypt: TBytes;
    begin
      GetOptions(Key, KeySize, InitVector, Encoding, ChainingMode, PaddingMode);
      Data := Encoding.GetBytes(DataMemo.Text);
      EncryptAES(Data, Crypt, Key, KeySize, InitVector, ChainingMode, PaddingMode);
      EncryptedMemo.Text := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(Crypt);
    end;

    procedure TMainForm.DecryptButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Keysize: integer;
      Encoding: TEncoding;
      ChainingMode: TChainingMode;
      PaddingMode: TPaddingMode;
      Key, InitVector, Data, Crypt: TBytes;
    begin
      GetOptions(Key, KeySize, InitVector, Encoding, ChainingMode, PaddingMode);
      Crypt := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(EncryptedMemo.Text);
      DecryptAES(Crypt, Data, Key, KeySize, InitVector, ChainingMode, PaddingMode);
      DecryptedMemo.Text := Encoding.GetString(Data);
    end;

    end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Android strings start from position 0. You can use `low(Data)` that will return the first character of string, also the library internally uses string from position 1, that won't run in android or ios. For multi-platform we shouldn't use `for i:=1 to length(string)` instead we should use `for l in string`

I think [LockBox3](https://github.com/TurboPack/LockBox3) should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Kohull for your comment!
I did read about the 0-offset strings in Android/IOS. That is why I tried [0] instead of [1]. But that didn't solve the problem. I now understand why. DCPcrypt internally still assumes strings with a 1-offset. So that won't work...

Comment: So I added {$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF} to all the DCPcrypt units in the hopes that that might do the trick. Unfortunately it did not.
So I have 2 options:
1. Go through all the DCPcrypt code and make it compatible with Android/IOS, or
2. Find another library that can do AES 256 encoding.
To start with options 2, do you maybe know of a library or unit that does AES 256 encoding that is compatible with Android/IOS?

Comment: Hi Kohull. Thanks for helping! I did look at LockBox, as well as numerous others I found. Once you start looking, you'll find many. But all had problems of some sort. In the end I resorted to adapting my code to work with DCPCrypt. I now have it working, both in Win32/64 as well as FMX on IOS and Android. I'll post the code in a separate msg.